# K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0] return "None". (Keras CNN visualization with tensorflow backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have CNN models trained using Keras with Tensorflow backend.
And I want to visualize my CNN filters with this tutorial: https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

model = load_model('my_cnn_model.h5')
input_img = np.load('my_picture.npy')

# get the symbolic outputs of each "key" layer (we gave them unique names).
layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers])

layer_name = 'block5_conv3'
filter_index = 0  # can be any integer from 0 to 511, as there are 512 filters in that layer

# build a loss function that maximizes the activation
# of the nth filter of the layer considered
layer_output = layer_dict[layer_name].output
loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

# compute the gradient of the input picture wrt this loss
grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

# normalization trick: we normalize the gradient
grads /= (K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(grads))) + 1e-5)

# this function returns the loss and grads given the input picture
iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])
```

However, when the code execute to this line:
`grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]`
I found it returns nothing but `None` object, so the program fail to progress after that.

I search for some solution. Some people say the`input_img` should be tensorflow's Tensor type:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5455

But when I tried to convert the img to Tensor, the problem is still exist.
I tried the solution in the link above, but still fail.

There is also someone say that this problem exists because your CNN model is not differentiable.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8478

But my model use only the activate function of ReLU and Sigmoid(at output layer).
Is this problem really caused by nondifferentiable problem?

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you provide your code and the complete error? Also, the only `NoneType` object that exists is `None`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 It returns “None” indeed! I pasted the code from the tutorial right now. The error message from tensorflow is so long, but I know that it is because the next function which use “grads” as parameter fails to deal with “None” variable. I think the gradients of the neural network is no possible to be None, right?

Comment: Well, it doesn't make all that much sense for it _to_ be `None`... But we can't help you unless you show us the code, the specific error message and what inputs you put in to create the problem. Bonus points if you can simplify the program and the problem still occurs.

Comment: What is input_img exactly? Can you show its definition?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro input_img is a numpy array with shape=(48, 48), dtype = float
it is a gray scale image, with every value range from 0 to 255.

Comment: @Jexus You can't take gradients with respect to a numpy array, it has to be with respect to a symbolic tensor that is connected to the graph.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I think you are right. Thank you very much! I will try to find how to build a symbolic tensor that is connected to the graph. Or can you give me some hints about how to it?

Comment: @Jexus Just look at my answer right below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a Model instance, then to take the gradient of the loss with respect to the input, you should do:

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
```

`model.input` contains the symbolic tensor that represents the input to the model. Using a plain numpy array makes no sense because TensorFlow then has no idea how this connects to the computational graph, and returns None as the gradient.

Then you should also rewrite the `iterate` function as:

```
iterate = K.function([model.input], [loss, grads])
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know where the problem is.

Comment: @Matias Valdenegro I'm facing a similar issue where I'm getting a NoneType, but in my case my model.input is the input to my fine tuned network, so I believe it's connected to the graph.  Do you have any suggestions?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310063/visualizing-convnets-filters-using-my-own-fine-tuned-network-resulting-in-a-none

Comment: @Jexus - were you able to get your code to work?  How did you alter your code to get it to work?

Comment: It would be very nice to complement this answer with how to use the function. We need `sess = K.get_session()` and `results = sess.run(iterate, feed_dict={model.input: numpyBatchWithData})`.

Comment: I think @DanielMöller shows how to use this function. I was calculating the gradient of the output of the network with respect to the input, and couldn't understand how to get this function to work `k.gradients(_, _)`. Thnx @DanielMöller!

Comment: Actually you don't need a session, iterate is a python callable, so you can just call it as a function

Answer (score 3):

Below, it's my example. Hope to help someone.

`gradient = keras.backend.gradients(model.output, model.input)[2]`

`iterate = keras.backend.function(model.input, [gradient])`

`grad = iterate([patches, depthes, poses])`

[patches, depthes, poses] is my model.input

Answer (score 1):

I too had faced the same error @Jexus. For me the problem was:

loss variable was None object. I had used

```
loss.assign_add(....)
```

instead of

```
loss = loss + .....
```

After changing that as mentioned, the loss was returning a tensor and hence

```
grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
```

wasn't returning None.